# eHome (Media Center) remote control not working in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, windows-media-center, remote-control

I'm using Windows 10 (OEM, cleanly installed), and trying to get my old Windows Media Center remote control to work (at least for volume, play, pause, next track, etc.)

The infrared receiver is detected, drivers are installed, and the appropriate devices show up in Device Manager ("Microsoft eHome Infrared Transceiver", etc.), the usbcir service is started, etc, but there's no reaction.

My keyboard's media keys work; I used a "ShowKey" utility to verify that my media keyboard sends the appropriate WM_APPCOMMAND messages, but nothing happens whatsoever when I use the remote control buttons (though I can see the receiver light up that it is receiving commands).  The receiver and remote work fine on a Windows 8 PC.

From what I understand the remote should work if it's the standard RC6 remote, which it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turns out to be with my dock (Dell TB 16 Thunderbolt dock).  When connected via the dock, it doesn't work.  When connected via a USB port directly to the laptop (a Dell XPS 13, so via USB-A-to-C adapter) it does work.

This has driven me crazy for months (since I got the laptop); I never would have expected it to be the dock, because it shows up correctly in Device Manager, but then I tried on a different Windows 10 machine and it did work.